# What are the differences between leaf and non-leaf pages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, database-internals

I've been running some index usage reports, and I'm trying to get a definition of **Leaf** and **Non-leaf**.  There seem to be both Leaf and Non-leaf Inserts, Updates, Deletes, Page Merges, and Page Allocations.  I really don't know what it means, or if one is better than the other.

If someone could give a **simple definition** of each, and also explain why Leaf or Non-leaf matters, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Think about it like this: leaf level pages are **the end of the road** for the data search through the B-tree structure of an index. They contain the data defined in the index definition (or in the case of a clustered index, all of the table's data) and a row locator to the data row (in the case of a nonclustered index).

Non-leaf level pages **contain the "road map" to the leaf level pages/data** by including the key value as well as a pointer to either another non-leaf level page (depending on the B-tree depth and location of the intermediate page) or the resulting leaf level page (index page for a nonclustered index, and data page for a clustered index).

Edit:  Here's a good image to put a picture to the idea.

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but you should link to your sources (especially when copying images): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

- leaf = In a clustered index,  where the all the row data data is. In a non-clustered index, the columns making up the index, plus any included columns and the clustered index key (if table has a clustered index)
- non-leaf = internal index node (contains only the column data that is part of the index)

Every index is comprised of a single root node, possibly several layers of intermediate internal tree nodes and a single layer of leaf nodes.

In a clustered index, the leaf nodes are effectively the table.
In a non-clustered index, the leaf nodes contain column data, any included columns and the clustered index keys.

[SQL Server Index Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/)